# Value of k so the density satisfies the probability conditions

Tags: probability

So there's a question which states
Find k if the probability density of x,y and z is given by

$f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} kyx(1-z) \, \, \,\text{if} \, 0<x<1 , 0<y<1, 0<z<1 , x+y+z<1\\ 0  \, \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

Will the upper limits of the integrals be $1-y-x , 1-x, 1$ and lower limits be all zero?

Comment: Your proposition makes complete sense to me, what do you get for $k$ when you apply it?

Comment: I'm getting k as -144 while the texbook says it is 144

Comment: I also get $k=144$, but you are definitely on the correct path: you now just need to find where this "-" is coming from. Also, if you look at it from the angle of how a density is defined: both $x$ and $y$ are positive, and, because of the constraints, $1-z$ is also positive, so it would make sense to find $k > 0$.